# AttributeError: module 'object_detection.protos.faster_rcnn_pb2' has no attribute 'AttentionPosition' - upon resuming training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, faster-rcnn

I am following this tutorial https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10.

System - Windows 10, Anaconda Prompt, Python 3.6, tensorflow 1.15.0

Initial setup and training are successful. Upon pausing the training and resuming I get the error message from the title. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that every time I reenter the environment from the anaconda prompt I should reset the python path. This solved the problem:

set PYTHONPATH=C:\tensorflow1\models;C:\tensorflow1\models\research;C:\tensorflow1\models\research\slim